# SQL Server 2012- execution plan - Split complex queries?

Tags: sql-server-2012, query-performance, sql-execution-plan

I have a complex/huge query (Select Statement) and i am trying to read and understand the way the optimizer is performing it.

It is quite difficult to interpret the plan because of the high number of operators.

The "main" query has many subqueries - Should I check the exeuction plans of these respective subqueries and approuch step-by-step to the "main" query- Or is this not recommend and I should take the entire query?

thanks in advance!
br Danijel

Comment: Big query is always bad. It's hard to SQL Server to optimize and for humor to read. SQL Server only takes good enough execution plan instead of the best. When query is huge, it may only examine a small portion of execute plans and then gives up.

Comment: @qxg thx for fast response!
Unfortunately I need to join those tables. The selected columns are going to be needed by an application for analysis and reportings.

how should i handle my problem ? Any ideas?
I perform all that by SSIS (Visual Studio)